MetisMenuJS sidebar not working properly (laravel+vujs) project
I've purchases a theme from themeforest (https://themesbrand.com/minible/layouts/index.html). They use metisMenujs which work fine in HTML & bootstrap. But I am convert this to my vuejs application which backend is laravel.
Problem is that the metismenu is not collapse properly. Though I have read the MetisMenuJs documentation (https://onokumus.github.io/metismenujs/) but can not find any solution. Need help of expert.
main of vue js
here is image of main vuejs code
side bar component
sidebar code and console error
console error
Thanks.

i can see that this theme using jquery did you check if the jquery installed in your project and make sure to rebuild you front-end sometimes rebuild the project fix it

How can I rebuild it. Can you please brife it. Thanks

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
